# Using netcoreapp2.1 APIs from libraries

Tags: c#, f#, .net-core

I'd like to use the [Span based GetBytes](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/23076/files) function available in *netcoreapp2.1* from a library; this is pretty low-level code. So library `L` wants to use the `ReadOnlySpan<char> * Span<byte> -> int` overload:

[image: API surface area in netcoreapp2.1]

And currently; domain library `D` (*netstandard2.0*) -> `L`, and app `A` (*netcoreapp2.1*) -> `D`.

What are the right framework targets for `L`, `A` and `D`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Comment: The only relevant passage there is that I can use netcoreapp2.1 to get access to the API I want, which is what my first sentence also states. I think part of the implicit question here is; a library is NOT an app, so is that just bad naming? And does it trigger a cascade update of all things that depends on it to at least netcoreapp2.1?

Comment: If your library is netstandard, I *think* you have to include System.Memory nuget package